# Email address links for user

Tags: html, database, email, mailto

I have a database system to keep track of students.  This is used by a few other people in the office who are not tech savvy.

I need to be able to email about 120 students at one time.  Given the character limit on URLs/browsers/what have you, using mailto is not an option; the character count is 2878.

Using a PHP form would make the most sense, but my unsavvy coworkers need to send email from Outlook.  Mainly so their sent mail reflects every message they've sent out.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you export your emails to excel or csv format and use outlooks's mailmerge feature?

Comment: Why not have the e-mail sent to them from PHP and then have the people they are sending to BCCed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the set of recipients is reasonably stable, the standard tool for this is a mailing list.  A closed mailing list can be set up on your mail server, or you can use something like Google Groups to create a closed list where people can enroll and unsubscribe as they see fit.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.  Is it possible to link a closed mailing list on the mail server to a MySQL database?

Comment: Depends on the mail server how easy or hard this is, but shouldn't be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could make it in php sending two emails:

1. One email to the receiver.
2. One email to the sender

You just need a rule in every Outlook that put the second email on the sent folder.